# Modo di dire per esprimere "parlare senza tabù"

Tags: idioms, phrase-request

Un giorno stavo cercando di esprimere l'idea di poter parlare con assoluta libertà di quegli aspetti dell'umanità o della vita delle persone dei quali di solito non si parla mai perché sono considerati tabù. Una persona italiana mi ha suggerito un modo di dire che adesso non ricordo bene. Penso che contenesse la parola "museruola". Ho cercato modi di dire con questo vocabolo e ho trovato "[mettere la museruola](http://www.impariamoitaliano.com/frasi10.htm)" ("far tacere, impedire a qualcuno di dire liberamente ciò che pensa, ridurne la libertà d'azione"). Tuttavia, questa espressione non fa riferimento a "parlare", ma invece a "tacere". Poi ho trovato il titolo di un libro su [Amazon](https://www.amazon.es/Aforismi-massime-parole-senza-museruola-ebook/dp/B00U05YJYS): *Aforismi, massime e parole senza museruola: La speranza è l'ultima a morire... prima tocca a noi!* Quindi, posso dire "parlare senza museruola"? E se non si tratta di un modo di dire, me ne potreste indicare qualcuno per esprimere questa idea?

Answer (score 9):

Aggiungerei le espressioni:

***Parlare [senza mezzi termini](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/senza-mezzi-termini)***: francamente, chiaramente, e

***Parlare [schietto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/schietto/)***, ossia in   in maniera chiara, senza remore.

De Mauro, Treccani

Comment: Si può utilizzare anche _parlar franco_

Comment: +1 queste sono le espressioni che ho sentito di più

Comment: *Parlar francamente* è un'ulteriore opzione.

Answer (score 8):

*"Parlare senza museruola"* non è, che io sappia, un modo di dire molto usato, ma il significato in questo contesto è chiaro: significa proprio parlare liberamente.

Si potrebbero utilizzare espressioni come ***"parlare [fuori dai denti](http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2015/04/16/espressioni-idiomatiche-con-la-parola-dente/)"*** che indica appunto il parlare apertamente, senza sottintesi o giri di parole; oppure mi viene in mente anche ***[“non avere peli sulla lingua”](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/P/pelo.shtml)*** per indicare il fatto di esprimersi con schiettezza, senza la paura di dire il proprio pensiero o la preoccupazione di un eventuale giudizio.

Zanichelli, Hoepli

Answer (score 2):

*"Parlare senza museruola"* è usato piuttosto sporadicamente, non è molto comune.
Ho sentito più volte il contrario, cioè *"mettere la museruola"* a qualcuno.

Aggiungerei anche le espressioni:

***Parlare chiaro e tondo***:

> In funzione avv., parlare, dire chiaro e tondo, con franchezza e
>   apertamente, senza preamboli o reticenze, soprattutto quando si
>   debbano dire cose spiacevoli: e io in vece vi dico chiaro e tondo che
>   il cuore in pace non lo metterò mai (Manzoni)

***Parlare senza tanti giri di parole***: parlare utilizzando termini facilmente comprensibili

> Giro di parole, perifrasi, circonlocuzione: dimmi chiaramente le cose
>   come stanno, senza tanti g. di parole; anche assol.: senza tante
>   storie e senza tanti Giri, si può benone in due parole ... (Giusti).

Fonti: Treccani

Answer (score 0):

Io userei anche:

> Non avere peli sulla lingua

[Word Reference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/senza-peli-sulla-lingua.2385263/)

Non ho trovato molto su Internet oltre a questo topic su Word Reference, ma ti posso assicurare che l'espressione "Non avere peli sulla lingua" è molto usata (nel nord Italia, non so se nel sud si dica).

Un esempio può essere il seguente:

> Marco è un bravo studente, la unica sua pecca è che non ha peli sulla lingua.

(= non riesce a stare zitto e dice tutto ciò che pensa)

Comment: È già stato proposto, nella risposta di Riccardo De Contardi...

Comment: Si trova nei dizionari, tipo Hoepli come citato sopra, ma anche altri.